# cochran.qtest error in binom.test

Tags: r, tidyr

This is my first post so hello everybody! I hope it will not be to nooby.

I have a problem of calculation Cochran Q-test for some of my data. 
I am receiving error that says:

> Error in binom.test(length(signs[signs > 0]), length(signs[signs != 0]),  : 
>    'n' must be a positive integer >= 'x'

This code helps to see what is happening (part of my data here):

```
Data <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)

Data <- as.data.frame(matrix(data, 5, 10))

library(RVAideMemoire)
library(tidyr)
tData <- as.data.frame(t(Data))
colnames(tData) <- c(rep(1:5))
tData$id <- factor(row.names(tData))
tData %>% tidyr::gather(tree, count, c(1:5)) -> tData2
xy <- cochran.qtest(count ~ id | tree, data = tData2, alpha = 0.05)
```

But if I subset my data, then it works. Where is the problem?

```
data <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)

data <- as.data.frame(matrix(data, 5, 10))

library(RVAideMemoire)
library(tidyr)
tData <- as.data.frame(t(Data[1:4,]))
colnames(tData) <- c(rep(1:4))
tData$id <- factor(row.names(tData))
tData %>% tidyr::gather(tree, count, c(1:4)) -> tData2
xy <- cochran.qtest(count ~ id | tree, data = tData2, alpha = 0.05)
```